# Speeding up a growing test suite with set up overhead

Tags: django, unit-testing

We have a unit test suite of approximately 150 tests that is growing quickly. We're using `Tastypie` to build an API and testing the functionality of each individual resource. We're using `FactoryBoy` to create our models/DB entries. We have a decent amount of database setup involved with each test. A typical SetUp method looks like this:

```
    self.customer_1 = Customer.objects.create_user(self.username, self.username,
            self.password)
    self.site = SiteFactory()
    Subscription.objects.create(customer=self.customer_1,
            site=self.site)
    self.post_1 = PostFactory(site=self.site)
    self.comment_1 = CommentFactory(post=self.entry_1,
            customer=self.customer_1)
```

Since SetUp is called before every single unit test, we're typically looking at 5-10 queries per test. It adds up. At 150 unit tests, it takes about 40 seconds to run on my Macbook Pro.

I'm not sure the team is ready/willing to use mocks for the database calls. Are there any other optimizations that could make running a Django/Tastypie test suite a little less painful? Perhaps some kind of caching for the SetUp calls?

Comment: http://www.daveoncode.com/2013/09/23/effective-tdd-tricks-to-speed-up-django-tests-up-to-10x-faster/, The application I am working on also has a large amount of initialization required, almost every test requires an object initialized to a certain state that requires  the amount of queries that you have, and my current run rate is:
`Ran 445 tests in 49.654s`
This is across 2 processes though.  If you use django-nose to run your tests you can choose how many processes to run your tests with, which is more of a band aid but perhaps could help